# USB not recognized on my laptop (MBR partition table)

Tags: windows, boot

I have HP6830 with Ubuntu 16.04.On my desktop, I have made USB bootable Windows 10.I have change boot order on my laptop but still, it does not boot from the inserted USB.

```
parted -l
Model: ATA FUJITSU MHZ2250B (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  248GB  248GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      248GB   250GB  2140MB  extended
 5      248GB   250GB  2140MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

My
[rufus settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbYYv.png)

And here are
[boot order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCtCW.jpg)

What should I do with my BIOS that would enable me to install Windows on my laptop?

Comment: By default windows 10 usb would be UEFI.

Comment: @jdwolf What should I do?

Comment: Did you use the Media Creation Tool?

Comment: NO,I have used rufus.

Comment: Rufus likely made a UEFI only boot disk or its possible you missed something else in the configuration. You can use Microsofts media creation tool which I'm pretty sure will work for you or if you want you can experiment around with settings in Rufus.

Comment: What's important in Rufus is that the windows be formatted using legacy partition table not gpt and make sure it still creates a bootable partition.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted a screenshot of the settings you used in rufus.

Comment: Ok,will try again and will post screenshots.

Comment: @jdwolf Can you take a look at my settings please?

Comment: have you checked to see if the BIOS considers your USB a harddrive? look to see if its in your list of harddrives in the boot priority.

Comment: @jdwolf I have added my boot order.

Comment: Try putting USB harddrive at the top if you haven't tried that?